# PostgreSQL recursive query for calculation parent value

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

Here is entry's hierarchy.

```
             _________Milky Way (30)________
            /               |               \
    Alpha(10)           Beta(20)            Delta(null)
     /  \                                       |
Mars(7) Jupiter(3)                          Delta-child(44)
```

Parents value is a sum of it's children's values.
Ex.

```
Alpha = Mars + Jupiter = 7 + 3 = 10
Milky Way = Alpha + Beta + Delta = 10 + 20 + null = 30
```

**The task:** recalculate parents up to the root  in case any child is updated. Let's even **simplify** the **task**: select all entries up to the root with recalculated values.
Imagine that *Mars* is updated. Now *Mars* value is 2.

```
             _________Milky Way (?)________
            /               |               \
    Alpha(?)            Beta(20)            Delta(null)
     /  \                                       |
Mars(2) Jupiter(3)                          Delta-child(44)
```

It means that all parents should be updated:

```
Alpha = Mars + Jupiter = 2 + 3 = 5
Milky Way = Alpha + Beta + Delta = 5 + 20 + null =  25.
```

*Note:* Delta -> Delta-child coupling is broken and it's fine. It can happen lets leave it out of scope here. 've added this sample just to be sure that it won't be counted during calculation as hierarchy can be huge enough and tehre is no task to recalculate all children leaf, just parents up to the root.

As a result of some "select .. from hierarchy.."
I'd like to receive recalculated parents' values. 
Ex.

| id | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Milky Way | 25 |
| 2 | Alpha | 5 |

Code samples with already updated *Mars* (sqlfiddle links are below):
**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE hierarchy
        (
        id int4,
        parent_id int4,
        name varchar(255),
        value int4
        );
```

**Values**

```
insert into hierarchy
values
(1, null, 'Milky Way', 30),
(2, 1, 'Alpha', 10),
(3, 1, 'Beta', 20),
(4, 1, 'Delta', null),
(5, 2, 'Mars', 2),
(6, 2, 'Jupiter', 3),
(7, 4, 'Delta-child', 44);
```

**What I have tried**:

1. I was able to list all leafs which should be used in calculation 
   [sqlfiddle 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/11c34a/5)

   ```
   WITH RECURSIVE cte AS ( 
     SELECT h1.id,  h1.parent_id, h1.name , h1.value from hierarchy h1
     where h1.id = 5
        UNION
    SELECT h2.id,  h2.parent_id, h2.name , h2.value from hierarchy h2
    JOIN cte cte ON (cte.parent_id = h2.parent_id or cte.parent_id = h2.id ) 
    where cte.id != h2.id 
   ) select * from cte
   order by id
   ```
2. When I tried to sum values, query goes in infinite loop for some reason
   [sqlfiddle 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/11c34a/10)

   ```
    WITH RECURSIVE cte AS ( 
     SELECT h1.id,  h1.parent_id, h1.name , h1.value from hierarchy h1
     where h1.id = 5
        UNION
    SELECT h2.id,  h2.parent_id, h2.name , (h2.value + cte.value) as value from hierarchy h2
    JOIN cte cte ON (cte.parent_id = h2.parent_id or cte.parent_id = h2.id ) 
    where cte.id != h2.id 
   ) select * from cte
   order by id
   ```
3. There is one more query that I have tried, unfortunately it doesn't count sibling of parents.
   [sqlfiddle 3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/11c34a/9)

   ```
               WITH RECURSIVE cte AS ( 
            SELECT h1.id,  h1.parent_id, h1.name , h1.value from hierarchy h1
             where h1.parent_id = (select parent_id from hierarchy where id = 5)  
                UNION
            SELECT h2.id,  h2.parent_id, h2.name , cte.value as value from hierarchy h2
            JOIN cte cte ON (cte.parent_id = h2.parent_id or cte.parent_id = h2.id ) 
            where cte.id != h2.id 
           ) select id, parent_id, name, sum(value) from cte
           group by id, parent_id, name
           order by id
   ```

I'd appreciate any assistance. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while, but good work on your trials.

What i did is that I split the problem in parts.

1. go down the hierarchy with the recursive query

```sql
with recursive base_qry as (
    select id, 
        parent_id,
        value,
        ARRAY[id] as id_array
    from hierarchy 
    union all 
    select h.id,
    h.parent_id,
    h.value,
    id_array || h.id as id_array 
    from hierarchy h join base_qry b on h.parent_id = b.id and h.value is not null
    )
```

2. Understand the nodes affected filtering the last id of the array containing all the nodes with `id_array[array_length(id_array,1)] = 5`

```
nodes_affected as (
    select * from base_qry 
    where id_array[array_length(id_array,1)] = 5
    order by array_length(id_array,1) desc
    LIMIT 1)
```

3. Find all the tree breanches than contribute to changed nodes (check here the filter for node `id=5`)

```
all_combinations as (
    select b.id, b.parent_id, b.value, b.id_array from
        base_qry b join nodes_affected n 
        on ARRAY[n.id_array] && ARRAY[b.id_array]
    where (b.id_array[array_length(b.id_array,1)] = 5 
        or b.id_array @> ARRAY[5] = false)
 )
```

aggregating up

```
select id_array[1]::int id, sum(value)
from all_combinations where id not in (select parent_id from all_combinations where parent_id is not null)
group by id_array[1]::int
order by 1
```

Whole query

```
with recursive base_qry as (
    select id, 
        parent_id,
        value,
        ARRAY[id] as id_array
    from hierarchy 
    union all 
    select h.id,
    h.parent_id,
    h.value,
    id_array || h.id as id_array 
    from hierarchy h join base_qry b on h.parent_id = b.id and h.value is not null
    ),
nodes_affected as (
    select * from base_qry 
    where id_array[array_length(id_array,1)] = 5
    order by array_length(id_array,1) desc
    LIMIT 1),
all_combinations as (
    select b.id, b.parent_id, b.value, b.id_array from
        base_qry b join nodes_affected n 
        on ARRAY[n.id_array] && ARRAY[b.id_array]
    where (b.id_array[array_length(b.id_array,1)] = 5 
        or b.id_array @> ARRAY[5] = false)
 )
select id_array[1]::int id, sum(value)
from all_combinations where id not in (select parent_id from all_combinations where parent_id is not null)
group by id_array[1]::int
order by 1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Start from the leafs and traverse all the nodes the leaf contributes to up the hierachy. Then just sum all contributions to a node.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS ( 
         SELECT id, parent_id, value
         FROM hierarchy h1
         WHERE not exists (select 1 from hierarchy h2 where h2.parent_id = h1.id) 
             UNION ALL
         SELECT h.id, h.parent_id, case when h.value is null then 0 else cte.value end 
         FROM hierarchy h
         JOIN cte ON (cte.parent_id = h.id) 
) 

select h.id, h.name, v.value
from (
   select id, sum(value) as value
   from cte
   group by id
) v
join hierarchy h on h.id = v.id
order by h.id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6160af5ad96df032ce8002c3ed28fd28)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE to get all nodes and their paths, and then for every non-leaf node in `hierarchy`, you can join the CTE back to `hierarchy` on the condition that the current hierarchy row id exists in the path and sum the values:

```sql
with recursive cte(id, p, n, v, t) as (
   select h.*, concat('[', h.id::text) from hierarchy h where h.parent_id is null
   union all
   select h.id, h.parent_id, h.name, h.value, concat(c.t, ', ', h.id)
   from cte c join hierarchy h on c.id = h.parent_id
)
select h.id, sum(c.v)
from hierarchy h join cte c on c.id != h.id and exists (select 1 from jsonb_array_elements(concat(c.t, ']')::jsonb) v where v.value::text = h.id::text) 
group by h.id order by h.id
```

Output:

```
id  sum
1   79
2   5
4   44
```